# What happens if you assign a new class on an existing instance?

Tags: java, android, class

Just a pretty simple question, in Java if I had an instance of my class set as a global variable, for example:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
```

If I then assigned a new instance of the class to it later in the code:

```
mc = new MyClass();
```

What happens to the old instance of the class, would it cause a memory leak and is this bad practice?

Cheers.

Comment: Java doesnt have global variables, just fyi.

Comment: as per the answers below its not a problem. the old value is garbage collected (assuming nothing else has reference to it). as for "bad practice", i believe it is preferable to assign a variable once and avoid reassigning it - but this is purely for readability and to reduce bugs. But in same cases, reassigning the variable is the cleanest solution, so its not a hard rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first MyClass is removed by garbage collection and mc is assigned to be a new MyClass, unless the first instance of MyClass is being referenced by another variable, in which case garbage collection does not destroy it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the entire point of managed memory. You don't need to manually clear or delete an object when you're done with it unless it's holding some other external resource like a network connection. The JVM (or, in this case, Android runtime) keeps track of objects, notices when they're no longer being used by anyone, and reclaims the memory.